# performing two tasks on right click of a file, c#

Tags: c#

i have added an item in the context menu of windows explorer using registry.
i want that when user right clicks on a file and then clicks on my added context menu item then an application must execute as well as location of that file must be availabe.

My application gets executed but i could not get the path of file on which i right clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How exactly did you add that context menu item? You need to pass the file name somewhere which is usually done by putting `%1` into the command line to be executed.

So if the command you're currently executing is

```
"C:\Program Files\MyCoolProgram\mcp.exe"
```

it should be

```
"C:\Program Files\MyCoolProgram\mcp.exe" %1
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here: [A simple C# function to add context menu items in Explorer](http://blog.voidnish.com/?p=17) and notice this part:

```
AddContextMenuItem(".zip", "ZipStrip",
  "Open with &ZipStrip", Application.ExecutablePath + " %1");
```

This way you'll receive your full file path as first argument on your `Main(string args[])`

**EDIT:** If you need to deal with arguments containing white spaces, try this:

```
AddContextMenuItem(".zip", "ZipStrip",
  "Open with &ZipStrip", Application.ExecutablePath + " ""%1""");
```

This way you argument will be enclosed into double quotes, preserving that white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The path is passed as a command line arguments. In the entry point, you can access it by defining a `string[]` argument:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // the path is passed in the `args` array.
}
```

It should also be available by calling [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).